# What is the expected number of days a student will study for if they have passed the exam?

Tags: probability

A students studies for an exam for at least one day. In the beginning, probability of failing the exam is equal to $1$. With every day of studying, the probability of failing the exam drops $c$ times. The probability of studying for another day is equal to $p$. 
What is the expected number of days a student will study for if they have passed the exam?

I tried to solve it like this:
Let $Y$ be a random variable that is equal to number of days that the student studies for. 
$$EY = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}{ i \cdot p^i \cdot \left(1-\frac{1}{c^i} \right)} $$

What does this series converge to, if anything? Is this even right?

Comment: Where is the probability $p$?

Comment: Ohh, right. I'll correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note* I'm pretty sure I've made a number of calculation errors, but the general idea should be correct

Let $Y$ be the number of days the student studied for the exam. Then

$$P(Y=k) = p^{k-1}(1-p)$$

Let $W$ be the probability that the student passes the exam. We know what

$$P(W \mid Y=k) = 1-c^k$$

from which we compute (Law of total probability)

$$P(W) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} P(W, Y=k) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} P(Y=k)P(W\mid Y=k) = (1-p)\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} p^{k-1}(1-c^k) = \frac{1-c}{1-pc}$$

Next, we compute

$$P(Y=k\mid W) = \frac{P(Y=k, W)}{P(W)} = p^{k-1}(1-p)(1-c^k)\frac{1-pc}{1-c}$$

Finally, we just need to compute the expectation of this

$$E[Y \mid W] = \sum_{k=1}^\infty kP(Y=k\mid W) = \frac{(1-p)(1-pc)}{p(1-c)}\sum_{k=1}^\infty kp^{k}(1-c^k) =$$
$$= \frac{1-p^2c}{(1-p)(1-pc)}$$

Comment: Why  $P(Y=k, W) = p^{k-1}(1-p)(1-c^k)$? Do you assume that $Y=k$ and $W$ are two independent events? I must say I have some problem with independence: I don't know when I can immediately assume that events are independent.

Comment: @Cachetejack Those events are clearly dependent. But I didn't write that $P(Y=k, W) = P(Y=k)P(W)$, which would be clearly wrong since the events are dependent. I wrote that $P(Y=k, W) = P(W\mid Y=k)P(Y=k)$, which does not require independence - it comes from the definition of $P(A \mid B)$